# How to compare different probability sets from different logistic models?

Tags: regression, probability, logistic

Do you know how to compare different sets of probabilities from different logistic models?

For example, I would like to predict customer's probability to buy four different products, i.e. A, B, C and D. So I developed four different logistic regression models to give four probability sets respectively.

Now I've probability sets A, B, C, D for all customers, but I want to know which product of four I should recommend to a customer. For example, a customer has a probability of 0.8 to purchase product A, 0.6 to purchase product B, 0.4 to purchase product C and 0.2 to purchase product D. Meanwhile, probability set A ranges from 0.7 to 0.9, while probability set B ranges from 0.5 to 0.6. I don't think simply sorting them in descending order is OK.

So do you know how could I compare these different probabilities from different logistic regression models? Thanks a lot!

PS I believe I've read somewhere that it could be done with some linear regression model, but I cannot remember clearly......pls help!

Comment: It depends on the interpretation of those probabilities, which in turn depends on the structure of your data.  Can you describe in detail how the data to fit these models was collected, and the structure of the training data itself?  What causes a record to appear in the training set?  What does "this customer purchased this product" mean?  Are all customers aware that all four products are available for purchase?  What does it mean when a customer did not purchase a product?  Was it because they were not aware of it, were aware and decided not to purchase, or something else?

Comment: @MatthewDrury I have to admit that it's just a fictional example, because I don't know how to summarize my question, sorry for that. For your questions, I think what I want to say is that the probability indicates the possibility for a customer to buy a certain product. Do you have any idea for summarization? Comparing 2 probability sets with different ranges?

Comment: Try using [these guidelines](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl) to provide enough detail that your question can be answered correctly.